# Ctypes, calling an external windll function

Tags: python, ctypes, mecab

I want to call some functions from an external dll using Python3 on Windows. The library and the functions I want to use are as below;

```
MECAB_DLL_EXTERN mecab_t*      mecab_new2(const char *arg);

MECAB_DLL_EXTERN const char*   mecab_sparse_tostr(mecab_t *mecab, const char *str);

MECAB_DLL_EXTERN void          mecab_destroy(mecab_t *mecab);
```

I need to call `mecab_new2` first, get the pointer from its return and use it on `mecab_sparse_tostr`, then finally dispose it using the same pointer by calling `mecab_destroy`.

I have found that the following works in C# (if it helps as a reference):

```
[DllImport(@"C:\libmecab.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private extern static IntPtr mecab_new2(string arg);
[DllImport(@"C:\libmecab.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private extern static IntPtr mecab_sparse_tostr(IntPtr m, byte[] str);
...
{
    IntPtr mecab = mecab_new2("-Owakati"); // returns a pointer
    mecab_sparse_tostr(mecab, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
```

But couldn't work out a similar way in python. I have tried the following with different restypes and argtypes. But the `mecab_new2` function always returns 0 (I assume its null?).

```
import ctypes

mecab_dll = ctypes.WinDLL(r"C:\libmecab.dll")
mecab_new2 = mecab_dll['mecab_new2']

mecab_new2.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)
mecab_new2.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p]

p1 = ctypes.c_char_p(b"-Owakati")
res = mecab_new2(p1)

print(res.contents)
# ValueError: NULL pointer access
```

If I remove the restype argument it returns 0, with `restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)` it returns a null pointer.

I've browsed similar questions and the documentation but couldn't find how. Am very bad with C++ and thus with ctypes as well.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT:** I've tried another function from the library, one that doesn't need any arguments and it worked out correctly. So I'm assuming my problem resides with arguments not matching? or the library is broken somehow?

Header file:

```
MECAB_DLL_EXTERN const char*   mecab_version();
```

Python code:

```
mecab_ver = mecab_dll["mecab_version"]
mecab_ver.restype = ctypes.c_char_p
print(mecab_ver()) # returns b'0.996' which is correct
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem might be here:

```
mecab_dll = ctypes.WinDLL(r"C:\libmecab.dll")
```

WinDLL means use Windows DLL calling convention (stdcall). However, in C#, you're using C calling convention (cdecl):

```
[DllImport(@"C:\libmecab.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
```

If your C# code works, try re-writing your ctypes call like this:

```
mecab_dll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r"C:\libmecab.dll")
```

**Edit:** You're also doing quite a bit of work to pass that string to your function. You should be able to simply do this (I'm not 100% certain this will work in Python3 - it works flawlessly in Python2):

```
mecab_dll = ctypes.cdll(r"C:\libmecab.dll")
res = mcab_dll.mecab_new2(b"-Owakati")
```

Python is quite intelligent about determining types in foreign functions - you shouldn't have to declare them unless you're doing something uncommon.

**Edit 2** This works for me, using Python 2, 32bit:
I'm doing this from an interactive prompt. Working directory is `C:\Program Files (x86)\MeCab\bin`

```
mecab = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libmecab.dll")
res = mecab.mecab_new2("-Owakati")
```

`res` is then a non-zero integer (appears to be a valid pointer).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that actually makes a lot of sense. But I still got the same result by calling `mecab_dll = ctypes.CDLL(r"C:\libmecab.dll")`. It throws `NULL pointer access` error.

Comment: I just made a few updates that might help - it also looks like you're passing a pointer to a string (char**) instead of a string (char*) to your mecab_new2 function.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply! Not knowing really what to do, jammed every solution that I can find =). But sadly result didn't change with the edit, still returns a NULL pointer.

Comment: Is the DLL publicly accessible? I can give it a try on my end.

Comment: That is awesome of you, you can find the source and the binary [here](http://taku910.github.io/mecab/#download) you need to change the source code and recompile If you are using 64-bit python. So it may be a headache (especially since all documentation about it is in Japanese) :(. It may take a bit time so I don't know if you really want to.

Comment: Done - tried it on python2 and got it working. Posted updated code.

Comment: Well I guess I somehow f***'d up something while changing the source. Thanks for all your work, I'll accept your answer and try to recompile.